# What is the difference between "миновать" and "минуть"?

Tags: глаголы

According to the dictionary, миновать is both perfective and imperfective. So I'm having trouble reconciling минуть: Does it indeed form part of the (hypothetical) verb pair минуть - муиновать, or is it considered a separate verb altogether? Also, is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: It's one and the same verb imperfective миновать,  perfective миновать and минуть (which is almost obsolete, but is still used in two meanings about age исполниться and about time which passed пройти.  There are examples on ruscorpora.ru.showing that it is still used.

Comment: ***миновать*** is mostly or exclusively used in physical sense of ***passing/going/flying by*** whereas ***минуть*** is mostly used figuratively

Answer (score 5):

`Минуть` in the majority of possible meanings has just become more of an obsolete form of `миновать`, here's a reduced quote from an article on [`минуть`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C):

1. `устар.` [устаревшее - obsolete] то же, что миновать; пройти, проехать мимо кого-, чего-либо, оставив кого-, что-либо позади или в стороне
2. устар. то же, что [миновать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C); пройти, не затронув кого-либо, не оказав никакого воздействия (обычно неблагоприятного)
3. обычно с отрицанием, устар. то же, что миновать; избежать чего-либо, уклониться от чего-либо
4. устар. то же, что миновать; не упомянуть о ком-, чём-либо, не коснуться кого-, чего-либо`

UPD: However I can recall at least one case when you should not trust dictionaries entirely - when one wants to say how much time passed by, `минуть` sounds more colloquial and less pathetic. For instance, compare `минуло семь лет` and `миновало семь лет`.